# XSL table output with mod

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I'm trying to output a table using XSL from a list of articles in the following format. The needs to be repeated, so full, split, split, full, split, split, etc.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Full</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Split</td>
        <td>Split</td>
    </tr>
    ... 
</table>
```

So the 1st and every forth article is a full article, but the rest are split articles and that row would contain 2x td's, not just one.

If I was doing this is PHP or similar I'd conditionally add the opening and closing tr's as required. It seems I can't do that in XSL. So I don't think I can use xsl:if on the tr's.

```
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="position() mod 4 = 0 or position() = 1">
    <tr>
        <td>Full</td>
    </tr>        
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
    <tr>
        <td>Split</td>
    </tr>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Many thanks

**EDIT** Here is the XML

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="template.xsl" version="1.0"?>
<rss version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>August 2011</title>
    <link>http://newsletters.falmouth.ac.uk/829a80a6-d28f-4f69-88e7-6177391b7eba/issue.aspx</link>
    <publication>Alumni e-Newsletter</publication>
    <publicationDescription>Alumni e-Newsletter</publicationDescription>
    <description>The school holidays are upon us and one thing that’s guaranteed is that the weather will be as unpredictable as ever!  But fear not, the Maritime Museum has the perfect solution for keeping the kids entertained come rain or shine.</description>
    <language>en-gb</language>
    <category>Alumni e-Newsletter</category>
    <generator />
    <lastBuildDate>Thu, 26 Jan 2012 14:03:46 GMT</lastBuildDate>
    <copyright>Copyright: (C) University College Falmouth</copyright>
    <ttl>15</ttl>
    <image>
      <title>This is a caption</title>
      <url>http://newsletters.falmouth.ac.uk/uploads/59026aae-27f8-4682-987f-632f1b4b6f77.jpg</url>
    </image>

    <item id="785">
      <title>Summer Holiday Activities 001</title>
      <link>http://www.nmmc.co.uk/newsletter/link.php?M=10940&amp;N=165&amp;L=248&amp;F=H</link>
      <description>&lt;P&gt;&lt;STRONG&gt;Until 4 September&lt;/STRONG&gt;&lt;BR&gt;Our school holiday activities are well under way and there are lots more to come.&amp;nbsp; Every week has a different theme and every day there’s a new creative craft activity to try.&amp;nbsp; And don’t forget there's crabbing every day from our pontoon.&lt;/P&gt;</description>
      <image>
        <title>August 2011</title>
        <description>Summer Holiday Activities</description>
        <caption />
        <url>http://newsletters.falmouth.ac.uk/uploads/22c0a56b-f372-4569-ae8c-9e0b475115f8.jpg</url>
        <width>190</width>
        <height>100</height>
      </image>
      <pubDate>Tue, 16 Aug 2011 14:39:54 GMT</pubDate>
    </item>

    <item id="779">
      <title>Douglas Dapper - The Story Explorer 002</title>
      <link>http://www.nmmc.co.uk/newsletter/link.php?M=10940&amp;N=165&amp;L=248&amp;F=H</link>
      <description>&lt;P&gt;&lt;STRONG&gt;Every Thursday until 1 September&lt;/STRONG&gt;&lt;BR&gt;Our Story Explorer will take you on a magical journey around the Museum to discover weird and wonderful tales from across the world.&amp;nbsp; Look out for pirates, polar bears and Packet ships throughout the summer.&lt;/P&gt;</description>
      <image>
        <title>August 2011</title>
        <description>Douglas Dapper - The Story Explorer</description>
        <caption />
        <url>http://newsletters.falmouth.ac.uk/uploads/ab01dbdf-d671-4127-9b9d-9aa6878bd97b.jpg</url>
        <width>190</width>
        <height>100</height>
      </image>
      <pubDate>Tue, 16 Aug 2011 10:58:12 GMT</pubDate>
    </item>

    <item id="780">
      <title>Two Castles Gig Race 003</title>
      <link>http://www.nmmc.co.uk/newsletter/link.php?M=10940&amp;N=165&amp;L=343&amp;F=H</link>
      <description>&lt;P&gt;&lt;STRONG&gt;7 August&lt;/STRONG&gt;&lt;BR&gt;Cheer on local pilot gig crews racing from St Anthony's Head to the Maritime Museum.&amp;nbsp; Watch on land from Events Square or get a ticket for the spectator boat to have a close up view on the water.&lt;/P&gt;</description>
      <image>
        <title>August 2011</title>
        <description>Two Castles Gig Race</description>
        <caption />
        <url>http://newsletters.falmouth.ac.uk/uploads/f0fe2730-a51f-4653-98d0-499ae8627635.jpg</url>
        <width>190</width>
        <height>100</height>
      </image>
      <pubDate>Tue, 16 Aug 2011 10:58:17 GMT</pubDate>
    </item>

    <item id="785">
      <title>Summer Holiday Activities 001</title>
      <link>http://www.nmmc.co.uk/newsletter/link.php?M=10940&amp;N=165&amp;L=248&amp;F=H</link>
      <description>&lt;P&gt;&lt;STRONG&gt;Until 4 September&lt;/STRONG&gt;&lt;BR&gt;Our school holiday activities are well under way and there are lots more to come.&amp;nbsp; Every week has a different theme and every day there’s a new creative craft activity to try.&amp;nbsp; And don’t forget there's crabbing every day from our pontoon.&lt;/P&gt;</description>
      <image>
        <title>August 2011</title>
        <description>Summer Holiday Activities</description>
        <caption />
        <url>http://newsletters.falmouth.ac.uk/uploads/22c0a56b-f372-4569-ae8c-9e0b475115f8.jpg</url>
        <width>190</width>
        <height>100</height>
      </image>
      <pubDate>Tue, 16 Aug 2011 14:39:54 GMT</pubDate>
    </item>

    <item id="779">
      <title>Douglas Dapper - The Story Explorer 002</title>
      <link>http://www.nmmc.co.uk/newsletter/link.php?M=10940&amp;N=165&amp;L=248&amp;F=H</link>
      <description>&lt;P&gt;&lt;STRONG&gt;Every Thursday until 1 September&lt;/STRONG&gt;&lt;BR&gt;Our Story Explorer will take you on a magical journey around the Museum to discover weird and wonderful tales from across the world.&amp;nbsp; Look out for pirates, polar bears and Packet ships throughout the summer.&lt;/P&gt;</description>
      <image>
        <title>August 2011</title>
        <description>Douglas Dapper - The Story Explorer</description>
        <caption />
        <url>http://newsletters.falmouth.ac.uk/uploads/ab01dbdf-d671-4127-9b9d-9aa6878bd97b.jpg</url>
        <width>190</width>
        <height>100</height>
      </image>
      <pubDate>Tue, 16 Aug 2011 10:58:12 GMT</pubDate>
    </item>

    <item id="780">
      <title>Two Castles Gig Race 003</title>
      <link>http://www.nmmc.co.uk/newsletter/link.php?M=10940&amp;N=165&amp;L=343&amp;F=H</link>
      <description>&lt;P&gt;&lt;STRONG&gt;7 August&lt;/STRONG&gt;&lt;BR&gt;Cheer on local pilot gig crews racing from St Anthony's Head to the Maritime Museum.&amp;nbsp; Watch on land from Events Square or get a ticket for the spectator boat to have a close up view on the water.&lt;/P&gt;</description>
      <image>
        <title>August 2011</title>
        <description>Two Castles Gig Race</description>
        <caption />
        <url>http://newsletters.falmouth.ac.uk/uploads/f0fe2730-a51f-4653-98d0-499ae8627635.jpg</url>
        <width>190</width>
        <height>100</height>
      </image>
      <pubDate>Tue, 16 Aug 2011 10:58:17 GMT</pubDate>
    </item>

  </channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: Without seeing input XML it's going to be almost impossible for anybody to help you.  Please read the [faq] and [ask]

Comment: I am downvoting to compensate for an upvote - the question does not have the input XML, and as such it is impossible to answer.

Comment: Added the XML, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try your own code? There's no reason you can't wrap tags in XSL conditions, as you have. Here's what I presume to be your intended result:

http://xmlplayground.com/9TXioN